# This link is broken. Delete it and share the item again

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, sharing-link

One of our SharePoint sites had a lot of documents shared for over a year via direct access links. Now, when we check the document's links, we get this error:

> This link is broken. Delete it and share the item again.

[image]

Does anyone know how this might have occurred and how to prevent it?

P.S. I am not a site owner and I don't know how these links were generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link will appear when you perform a "**Copy link**" operation on a file/folder.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is a New OneDrive & SharePoint Feature: **Fixing Unhealthy Sharing Links**. If now including these "unhealthy" links in Manage Access. SharePoint will notify the user that the link is broken and must be deleted and recreated.

**For example:**

A user makes some permission changes (such as breaking inheritance manually via permissions API's) that can cause sharing links to become unhealthy, which means the links exist but they no longer grant actual access to the item.

For more information, please see "**[New OneDrive & SharePoint Feature: Fixing Unhealthy Sharing Links](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/onedrive-for-business/new-onedrive-amp-sharepoint-feature-fixing-unhealthy-sharing/m-p/1183274#M6765)**" Blog.